# PHP error when uploading to hosting CPANEL

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, cpanel

I got that error after upload my work to hosting CPANEL. In my localhost it's okay, but in hosting I got error:

> Module 'mysqli' already loaded in CODEIGNITER

Answer (score 1):

Open

> /usr/local/lib/php.ini

locate mysqli and remove dupliate entrys.

Restart apache.